# Utility to check for plagiarism in GitHub repositories

Tags: github, duplicate-files, plagiarism-detection

I'm looking for a utility that can check a GitHub repository and estimate whether or not the codebase was probably a fork from another popular repo, or that it has huge amounts of plaguarised code within the repo.

The features I'm looking for:

- Compare a collection of repositories to a 'suspect' repository
- Check for duplicate files
- Check for similar files
- Check for similar directory structure

My usecase is for evaluating the legitimacy of new blockchain startups, as I suspect most are just clones of other more popular projects.